# PHP DateTime UK Summer Time

Tags: php, laravel, datetime

I have a drag and drop rota application which works fine except for Sunday 30th October (when our clocks go back an hour).
The user drags a time and duration box onto a date and the system calculates. Unfortunately on the 30th of this month the system is deducting 1 hour from the start time.
I have tried adding date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London') at the top of the method. Also adding $start_date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/London')); in various places without any success.

```
        /* Pull in date from rota in format 20-10-2016 */

    $date = Input::get('date');

    /* Pull in the details of the shift */

    $actions = Rotaaction::find(Input::get('action_id'));
    $duration = $actions->duration;

    /* Set the start date/time of the shift */

    $start_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',$date);
    $start_date->setTime(0,0,0);
    $start_date->add(new DateInterval("P0000-00-00T$actions->start_time"));

    /* Set the finish date/time of the shift */

    $end_date = Clone $start_date;
    $end_date->modify("+{$duration} minutes");
```

So far I have added an 'if' that adds an hour on that date,  but there must be a 'proper' way.
Your help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you change timezone in your `config/app.php` file?

Comment: Yes this is set to 'Europe/London' thanks